# Cakephp: How to change the salt and cipherseed after the application is live

Tags: cakephp

I have a deployed cakephp 1.3 application that running without issue. But I am switching the development teams on the project and I would like to change the salt and cipherseed just to be safe.

How is this done?

Comment: By editing the core.php file - is there more to your question?

Comment: No - if it is that simple. I have a running application with information in the DB. My first thought is that the encrypted data would no longer be accessible if I change those values.

Comment: Anything that uses the salt will be invalidated - e.g. Passwords. You can't change the salt without that being a direct concequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **CAUTION:**
>   The following steps are not necessarily meant to be completed in order.
>   **Read over the whole thing
>   first to understand the entire process!**
>
> **If you go step-by-step, you'll break current
>   user's ability to log-in to your site.**  For example, you should build out #3 & #4 before doing #2 - but it is easier to understand when explained in the following order:

**1) Retain old salt**

First, copy your current salt, and save it somewhere.

**2) Change site salt value**

Then, go into your `app/Core/config.php` file and change salt value.

> **Warning:**
>
> Keep in mind, any previously hashed passwords...etc will be invalid. 
>   There's not really a way to get them back, so at that point, you'll
>   need to create some kind of segway for users to get  a new password.

**3) Create a segway for user to validate**

Create a process where a user can go in and enter their username/old_password for you to verify against using `Security::hash($oldPass, 'sha1', $oldSalt);`.  [[more details here]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html#Security%3a%3ahash)

**4) Have them create a new password**

Once you verify they're who they say they are, you can allow them to create a new password just like you would have before using the sites $salt value.

*Pardon if I have any syntax errors (off the top of my head), but this should give you an idea of one way to handle it.